# Run long container job on AWS once

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a simple need: I need to run an arbitrary container job on AWS once.

I need `docker run <container_image> program.py arg1 arg2 arg3`, but on AWS cloud. Not a service. Not an app. Not a VM. A container job. A script that starts, runs for couple of minutes or hours, then finishes.

What is the best Amazon service to use for such task?

Most services are not aligned with the "run container job once" task. Lambda runs forever and does not run arbitrary container command lines. EC2 runs forever and AFAIK is a VM, not just container. Amazon Kubernetes requires cluster setup which takes a lot of time and is expensive.

With Google Cloud I can use Vertex AI CustomJob for such task: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/CustomJobSpec#containerspec

Comment: I'm not sure what is the issue? Normal ECS task runs only once. So what are you not using it? It does not work for you?

Comment: It's really confusing: "Amazon ECS is a fully managed container orchestration service that helps you easily deploy, manage, and scale containerized applications." - services, applications... I'll try to read about "ECS Tasks".

Comment: ECS services is different then ECS task. ECS task runs only once, till the container finishes. ECS service keeps your container running forever.

Comment: I see. What's the latency ballpark? How long does it take to run "Hello World" container job? 5 seconds? 5 minutes? Do you pay per CPU time (and machine type)?

Comment: I was also looking at Fargate a bit. Also Batch. I'm pretty confused by all the services,  their features and differences.

Comment: You can run ECS Task on Fargate. It is the easiest way to run a task.